# turning Russia into a ringed-off economic fortress - what does ringed-off mean?

Tags: meaning

Source: http://finance.yahoo.com/news/world-war-russia-mind-u-084905338.html

> Still, turning Russia into a **ringed-off** economic fortress isn't at the heart of Glazyev's prescriptions. Faced with a souring climate abroad, the country should promote import substitution and policies aimed at reversing the brain drain that's sapped Russia's scientific prowess.

What does **ringed-off** mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ring-off here [means](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/ring_6) to isolate something. (alt. insulate, remove (from the world), separate, disconnect, et al.)

Comment: A similar term is roped-off.

Comment: 'Ring-fenced' is a more familiar term meaning isolated etc